# Magnetohydrodynamic Walens Equation

Tags: vectors, plasma-physics, magnetohydrodynamics

How to derive Walens Equation from Continuity Equation and Induction Equation.

Continuity Equation:

$\frac{d \rho}{dt} + \rho \nabla.v + v.\nabla\rho=0$

Induction Equation:

$\frac{dB}{dt}= -B(\nabla.v)+(B.\nabla)v-(v.\nabla)B$

Using these two Equations we should get the Walens Equation:

$\frac{D}{Dt}\left(\frac{B}{\rho}\right)=\left(\frac{B}{\rho}.\nabla\right)v$

None of the books have mentioned how to derive it and I am not sure how to either.

I first applied material derivative and got rid of the third term in the induction equation:

$\frac{DB}{Dt}=-B\nabla.v+B.\nabla v$
then should we assume it's an incompressible fluid hence $\nabla . v=0$ can be substituted and we finally get the expression which can be divided by $\rho$ to get the Walens Equation.

Is it right to assume it as incompressible fluid and derive it?

Comment: Does this help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/436557/how-to-derive-walens-equation#442157

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to derive Walen's equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/436557/how-to-derive-walens-equation)

Comment: i didnt understand how to go from eq(4) to eq(5) in:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/436557/how-to-derive-walens-equation

Comment: @MilesChase Well Eq (5) doesn't come from Eq (4), it is just an application of the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) for $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}t$ on the ratio $B/\rho$.